# AppInstallerRedirector terminal

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, python-3.7, python-venv, virtual-environment

I use python 3.7.4 on my system.
I tried creating a virtual environment on VS code for a project in the cmd terminal, but as soon as I enter the command `python3 -m venv myEnv` the terminal name changes from *cmd* to *AppInstallerPythonRedirector* and nothing happens.
I want help figuring out why this is happening and how to fix the issue and create a new environment for my project

Answer (score 1):

The command `python3 -m` is for macOS/Linux. If you are using Windows, it should be `py -3`. Steps to create and activate the virtual environment for windows:

1. Create the virtual environment:

   ```
    py -3 -m venv .venv
   ```

   **Note**: When you create a new virtual environment, you should be prompted by VS Code to set it as the default for your workspace folder. If selected, the environment will automatically be activated when you open a new terminal.

   [image]
2. Active the environment:

   ```
    .venv\scripts\activate
   ```

   If the activate command generates the message *"Activate.ps1 is not digitally signed.
   You cannot run this script on the current system."*, then you need to temporarily change the PowerShell execution policy to allow scripts to run (see About Execution Policies in the PowerShell documentation):

   ```
    Set-ExecutionPolicy -ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned -Scope Process
   ```
3. Select your new environment by `Ctrl+Shif+P`, **Select Interpreter command from the Command Palette**.

If you are macOS/Linux, just follow:

https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments#_global-virtual-and-conda-environments